# How to run headless YUI tests and log success/failure in a log file?

Tags: c#, javascript, .net, yui

I have some YUI tests which I need them to run headless. Currently, these tests are run by launching their corresponding *TestFileName.html*. Upon launching, the browser shows passed or failed tests on the screen with green and red icons and their corresponding messages. During this process, the machine is unusable because the browser's UI keeps popping up and down.

I am trying to make the test run headless. For that I created a WebBrowser (from .NET) control in memory and launched the page in it. But, this way I can not see the UI and determine if the tests passed of failed. I need to log the success/failure and corresponding messages in a log file in file system.

I am not sure how to do so. Can someone please tell me what can I do to achieve headless execution of YUI and creating the logs?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at Phantom.js.  It's a head-less version of WebKit (ie. Safari and Chrome), and people use it all the time for running head-less JS tests, so you can probably find a lot more information out there for it than for that .NET thing you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

YUI provides a Node.js command line tool named "grover" that does exactly this: https://github.com/yui/grover

Use npm to install grover and then run 'grover paths/to/test/files.html ...' You can also use grover to generate code coverage reports.